# Count entries in a JSON Array?

Tags: php, json, loops, data-extraction

How do I count the entries I am scraping from JSON?

The below example has 6 entries, but as you can see.. if an entry is added, my code will ignore it. I could loop it 10 times and if it picks up nothing, then stop, but I think that's a bad way of doing it.

Is there any simple code that picks up 6 'seasons' in the following JSON?

**MYPAGE.PHP**

```
//Get the page
$str = file_get_contents('http://myjsonurl.here/');
$jsonarray = json_decode($str, true);

$season1 = $jsonarray['season_history'][0][0];
$season2 = $jsonarray['season_history'][1][0];
$season3 = $jsonarray['season_history'][2][0];
$season4 = $jsonarray['season_history'][3][0];
$season5 = $jsonarray['season_history'][4][0];
$season6 = $jsonarray['season_history'][5][0];
//the rest of the info here..
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "season_history": [
        ["2006/07", 2715, 12, 11, 0, 45, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 26, 0, 91, 169],
        ["2007/08", 2989, 15, 11, 0, 56, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 18, 0, 95, 177],
        ["2008/09", 2564, 9, 10, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 14, 0, 95, 138],
        ["2009/10", 2094, 12, 6, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0, 92, 130],
        ["2010/11", 2208, 21, 4, 8, 28, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 26, 0, 92, 176],
        ["2011/12", 521, 7, 0, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 146, 89, 49]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `foreach` loop may be the approach you're looking for.

For example, this code would output the years for each season in your JSON data, regardless of how many seasons there were:

```
//Get the page
$str = file_get_contents('http://myjsonurl.here/');
$jsonarray = json_decode($str, true);

foreach($jsonarray['season_history'] as $season) {
    echo $season[0] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Alternatively, if you just need to know the number of seasons, this would be a solution:

```
//Get the page
$str = file_get_contents('http://myjsonurl.here/');
$jsonarray = json_decode($str, true);

$numberOfSeasons = count($jsonarray['season_history']);
```

You could combine that with a `for` loop as well, if you wanted:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $numberOfSeasons; $i++) {
    echo $jsonarray['season_history'][$i][0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.. I figured it out... Here is the code I used.

```
//Get the page
$str = file_get_contents('http://myjsonurl.here/');
$jsonarray = json_decode($str, true);

//FOR EACH SEASON
foreach ($jsonarray['season_history'] as $var) 
{
for ($i = 0; $i <= 15; $i++)
    {
     echo $var[$i];
     //do more stuff here
    }

}
```